# Will QuickBooks API Work With Custom Apps?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbxml

We've developed some custom apps for clients which connect to QBO via the QBSDK. Since the new Harmony interface in QBO will break QBSDK apps, does this mean that Intuit will support the use of the IPP with custom apps? Does anybody have info about Intuit's plans for this?

Comment: Intuit said they'd announce this in a month or so. Until then, I think everything is up in the air. I'd submit a support ticket and ask Intuit about it to see if they can give you more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom integration is still not supported in production.

You can follow the IPP's official blog.

https://developer.intuit.com/blog

You can use QB REST APIs in the dev only mode. But in that case there will be a constraint of 10 active connections(app-company).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On December 19, 2013, Intuit announced that they are supporting integration.  It looks like they are handling integration by "Publishing to Your Private Channel"; same path as publishing an app on their Apps.com but will less requirements and approvals.

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/19/2014-roadmap-and-migration-dates-for-existing-developers

What's more, they are expecting all QBOE customers to migrate to their new v3 API by March 15, 2014.  If you don't, your existing integration will fail once they migrate your company to their new "Harmony" version.  They plan to migrate everyone over to harmony by July.

This is a aggresive timeline so I would not be surprised if the dates slip.